Notification show up as html on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
All notification show up as html with tags. This happens on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS build. Any idea how to remove it and view it as normal. These are desktop notifications coming up from Telegram Desktop app installed from the App Center.
For example it shows up as
<b>Name</b> Some text here.
ideally, it should display as
Name Some text here.
Screenshots:



Welcome to AskUbuntu! This is not an issue I’ve seen on any of my 24.04 installations. Could you [edit] your question to include some screenshots? This may make it easier to narrow down a pattern.

I'm having the same issue with rhythmbox notifications, also since 24.04

I have created a bug report for it, please visit and confirm that you are affected to confirm it in the system: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnotify/+bug/2071511

try sending yourself a notification like notify-send "<i>foo</i> - <b>bar</b>" to confirm

Thanks @Batwam, for validating the issue. Not exactly a showstopper issue but definitely worth a fix. Sending a notification like notify-send "foo - bar" also confirms this issue.
